# Google App Engine alternative for CentOS, Fedora, Ubuntu?

Tags: centos, fedora, python, chrome

I have written WebRTC Apps which is Python and Google App Engine.

Google App Engine is not freely available to use for production release, so I am looking alternative of it for CentOS, Fedora.

Is there a  working/stable/production version for use like alternative Google App Engine for CentOS, Fedora.

Comment: What is your purpose? If you look for some plug-and-play replacement of Google App Engine API I guess this wouldn't be possible (because of API copyright): you would have to rewrite part of your WebRTC Apps in order to use another service. Which service is the most suitable to your purpose depends probably on what you are using app engine for (they have a lot of features, I don't expect to find all of them in the same package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some projects that you should investigate and that may meet your needs

- [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/get-started/), [source](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale) (Python, Java, PHP, Go)
- [Cape Dwarf](http://capedwarf.org/), [source](http://capedwarf.org/source/) (Java only currently)

There are a lot of options to deploy yourself and it's likely the virtual machine option is the most easy to get started.  Since the source is there you should be relatively free to compile or customize for your needs.

Comment: AppScale is it well enough mature for Python please????